# AWS - ECS : Unable to create service: Reason: Stack [ECS-Console-V2-Service-xxxxxx-yyyyy-7234ffe4] already exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I had a service in ECS. I have deleted it and trying to create a new one, because I wanted to attach a load balancer.  There is no way to attach service after the service is created.

I keep getting

[image]

What to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to view in cloudformation and delete the cloudformation this is pointing to. And recreate your service with LB. This helped me.

Comment: Can you explain more the solution? Can you write, step-by-step howdid you solve the issue? Thanks.